# Writing to an interactive prompt

Tags: shell, io-redirection, ftp

I’m using the `ftp` command line tool and want combine scripted input with user input. With only user input the prompt looks like this:

```
ftp>
```

But when I try to insert some input with a script, like

```
{echo "user username passwd"; cat;} | ftp -n server.tld
```

How can I force `ftp` (or any cli) to still use the interactive mode?

I would prefer a solution based on standard shell tools.

Comment: I would switch to the `lftp` client for starters if you're attempting to do any scripting of FTP. The cli `ftp` is pretty weak in comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a program to interact with interactive command line tools exactly like the `ftp` example: [`expect`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/expect.1.html).  It is a specialized script shell, extending the on the scripting language `tcl`.

It is very powerful, but you may get away without learning everything about it. A very useful tool is [`autoexpect`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/autoexpect.1.html), which can record an interactive session as an expect script. The recorded script is certainly helpful to understand the basics.

A `expect` script can interact with an interactive program like `ftp`. 
This can be combined with interaction of the user and the interactive program. Using the command `interact` in an `expect` script, the control can be given to the user temporarily.
While the user has control, the script still listens for events to take back the control, so practically, both the user and the script are interacting simultaneously with the program.

Comment: Indeed it is possible to give control to the user via expects `interact` command.

Comment: @canaaerus yes, that's what I meant; Added some details on it.